# Finding Fault Code from Register Dump

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to debug a crashing custom boot loader. I am running it in QEMU, and am getting the following register dump:

```
Triple fault
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000080 ECX=0005ff60 EDX=000258a8
ESI=0422fba0 EDI=0422fb90 EBP=00050000 ESP=0005ff5c
EIP=00025c8b EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 000fffff 004f9e00 DPL=0 CS32 [CR-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     0002ea88 00000038
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000001c CCD=0005ff58 CCO=CLR     
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

I suspect that the root cause of the triple-fault is trying to execute an invalid processor instruction (in this case, `rdrand`). However, I cannot confirm that because I don't know where in the above dump the exception code is.

Comment: A triple fault happens if you don't have handlers for the normal faults or the double faults. You might want to set those up instead, or use a debugger.

Comment: A triple fault happens when an attempt to invoke the double fault handler results in fault. A double fault happens when an attempt to invoke any fault hauler results in a fault. So you won't find the root of the problem, what caused the first fault, in the dump for the third fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was indeed an invalid-instruction fault that was causing this. I proved this through looking at a disassembly of the boot loader and comparing it against the Intel ISA documentation.